# Group the data in one column per the values in another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have data something as below

```
email id           subject of interest
ramesh@axito.com       Java,C++
mnp@axito.com            VB
ramesh@axito.com        Python
mohan@axito.com        Java,C++
mnp@axito.com            JS
rohan@axito.com         C#
```

But I need it in the format as below-

```
email id           subject of interest
ramesh@axito.com       Java,C++,Python
mnp@axito.com            VB,JS
mohan@axito.com        Java,C++
rohan@axito.com         C#
```

Can someone please tell me how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

First, create the list of unique email addresses with `=unique(A2:A)`. Suppose this is done in column C.

Then in cell D2, enter `=join(",", filter(B$2:B, A$2:A=C2))` and drag this formula down columd D.

Explanation: `filter` keeps only the entries from column B with matching email; `join` joins them into a comma-separated list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help..:) Now I have one more query..I have to check who all are interested in a particular language..For example if I search with email id "ramesh@axito.com" then I should get the output as "Java,C++,Python"..Is it possible?? through Google spreadsheet script or Excel script..?

Comment: Thanks for the help..I have below spreadsheet which as list of site owners. I want to check which email id has owner access to sites. Like a single email id can have owner access to many sites. So i need that. Can you please tell me how can i do this using google app script? Here is the sheet lik https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xeLZk1AKUCj7sbBrcAaJRl5MON2zkxVwcfssG3Wgzpw/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1):

Try using query function:

```
=QUERY({A:B,A:B},"select Col1, Count(Col2) where Col1 <> '' group by Col1 pivot Col4")
```

Also try this formula, this is single formula solution:

```
={UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A>0)),TRANSPOSE(
   SPLIT(
      ", "&join(", ",
         ARRAYFORMULA(
            if(query(A:B,"select A where not A is null order by A",0)=
               query(A:B,"select A where not A is null order by A limit "&COUNT(query(A:B,"select A where not A is null",0))-1,1),"","|")
             & query(A:B,"select B where not A is null order by A",0)
             & " "
         )
      )
   ,", |",0)
)}
```